# Elevation Values using Nasa WorldWind SDK

Tags: java, gis, worldwind

I'm currently using Nasa worldwind SDK so as to get the exact elevation of a precise point on Earth . The problem is that i'm getting wrong values . I don't know if it's related to some zoom stuff seeing that I'm not so familiar with this SDK .

I'm very thankful for ur help  Here's the code snippet i'm using :

```
     m = (Model) WorldWind.createConfigurationComponent(AVKey.MODEL_CLASS_NAME);
     worldWindowGLCanvas1.setModel(m);

     nasa=m.getGlobe();
     Angle lat,longitude;
     lat=new Angle(Angle.fromDegreesLatitude(clicked_Geoposition.getLatitude()));
     longitude=new Angle(Angle.fromDegreesLongitude(clicked_Geoposition.getLatitude()));
     double test=nasa.getBestElevation(lat,longitude);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there may be a bug on the second to the last line. Should it be the following instead?

```
   longitude=new Angle(Angle.fromDegreesLongitude(clicked_Geoposition.getLongitude()));
```

Comment: I'm so sorry , it's a shame !   I was so tired after 7 hours of coding that i'm made this silly mistake . Thank you for your help . I should quit programming :(

Comment: No need to apologize. That's what code reviews are for. I'm glad that fixed the problem and hope you were able to get some sleep!